# Convert a non-supported/obscure codec to a supported codec

Tags: codec, avi

I currently work with a team of researchers and we are obtaining data from videos that are encoded with SMB8, they are AVI files. We couldn't find anything on the SMB8 codec online unfortunately. We would like to convert these raw AVI videos with SMB8 to H.265 HEVC videos using a converter such as FFMPEG or into another readable codec. Our current issue is that our new software does not read SMB8 files.

I apologise for any inaccuracies or typos, I'm not an expert on video production and I typed this question on mobile.

Thanks!

Comment: Share the output of `ffmpeg -report -i file`.

Comment: @Gyan https://pastebin.com/x8VvspnK

Answer (score 1):

I found a reference to this codec perhaps being used by the SIMI motion capture software; chances are it's uncompressed (if a high bit rate?) or lightly compressed AVI with additional data streams. Perhaps some stupid bitstream obfuscation... Less likely, but perhaps just a commodity codec like ASF/WMV in an AVI container?

Discussion of SIMI software found on http://birdz.sk/forum/avi-nevie-pehrat-ziaden-prehravac/138108-tema.html/ . Perhaps contacting the software developer is worth a shot.

If not, I'd try experimenting with the FOURCC changer (https://www.fourcc.org/changer/) and see if you can get WMP, VLC or mplayer to accept this file without baulking at any ancillary data.

Maybe ffmpeg could be forced to demux just the video assuming a format, allowing you to reencode? Have you got a clip available to post for analysis?

Comment: Hey, I'll try to use the FourCC Changer and see what the results are.

Comment: So I found that converting the FOURCC from "SMB8" to "MRLE" (Microsoft RLE) allows me to convert the video with FFMPEG to a playable .mp4, however, the color is in B & W.

Comment: It could store separate planes one after another, couldn't say more without looking at actual video file.